# (...).mockImplementation is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've used this test in the past with a React app without any issues:

```js
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import { RelatedContent } from '../components/relatedcontent'
import { onValue } from '../components/firebase'
jest.mock('../components/firebase')

test('RelatedContent -> displays related content', async () => {

    let fakeData = {
            
        'flex-new-row': 20,
        'chronlabs': 25
        
    }

    let snapshot = {val: () => fakeData}

    onValue.mockImplementation((ref, callback) => {

        callback(snapshot)

        return jest.fn()

    })
        
    render(<RelatedContent numRelated = {5}/>)
    
    await waitFor(() => expect(document.querySelector("a[href='/flex-new-row']")).toBeTruthy())
    await waitFor(() => expect(document.querySelector("a[href='/chronlabs']")).toBeTruthy())
    
})
```

Now I'm using the same test on a Next.js app, and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: _firebase.onValue.mockImplementation is not a function
```

### Update

The RelatedContent component looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { db, onValue, ref } from './firebase'

const RelatedContent = ({ numRelated }) => {
    
    const [related, setRelated] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {

        let unsubscribe = onValue(ref(db, `posts/related`), snapshot => {
            
            let _related = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
            
            setRelated(_related)
            
        })
        
        return () => unsubscribe()
        
    }, [])
    
    return(
        <div className = 'Related'>
            {related.slice(0, numRelated).map((elem, i) => 
                <Link href = {elem}>Whatever</Link>
            )}
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default RelatedContent
```

And the Firebase component looks like:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getDatabase, goOnline, goOffline, limitToLast, onDisconnect, onValue, orderByValue, push, query, ref, remove, runTransaction, update } from 'firebase/database'

const config = { ... }

const app = initializeApp(config)

const db  = getDatabase(app)

export { db, dbt, goOnline, goOffline, limitToLast, onDisconnect, onValue, orderByValue, push, query, ref, remove, runTransaction, update }
```

**`package.json`** looks like:

```json
{
    "name": "app-next",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@primer/octicons-react": "^16.3.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
        "firebase": "^9.6.4",
        "gfm": "0.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "next": "12.0.8",
        "prismjs": "^1.26.0",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "react-markdown": "^8.0.0",
        "rehype-katex": "^6.0.2",
        "rehype-raw": "^6.1.1",
        "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
        "remark-math": "^5.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
        "eslint": "8.7.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
        "jest": "^27.4.7"
    }
}
```

If I place the fake data and the `onValue.mockImplementation()` function before the test declaration, the test passes correctly.

The problem is that I've several tests with multiple definitions of the fake data, and I need to declare the fake data within every test.

If I do so, I get the error.

Comment: please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What's your `RelatedContent` component looks like? How the `firebase.onValue` be used?